# Как выйти из корневой папки? [Nginx/PHP]

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, apache, файловая-система

постараюсь объяснить как моего короче.

Имеется PHP проект, структура которого следующая:

Core

Public

```
index.php
```

Vendor

...

В качестве веб сервера я использую Nginx и Apache переменно.

Суть вопроса и проблема следующая, Nginx настроен таким образом, что открывает папку Public и читает index.php, но проблема в том, что мне необходимо, чтобы index.PHP подхватил файлы, которые лежат в корне проекта.

В Docker есть переменная $_ENV["WORKDIR"] и $_SERVER["WORKDIR"], которые без Docker недоступны.

В laravel аналогичная система файлов, папка public и index.PHP, которые имеют доступ к файлам в корне проекта. Пытался понять как это реализовано в laravel, но так и не смог выяснить. Какие есть идеи и решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Да хоть `../Core/`, хоть абсолютный путь пишите. PHP всё равно, главное чтобы доступ к файлу был...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar ../Core/ лишь добавит../Core/ к папке public и выйдет следующее: public/../core/

Comment: Так всё правильно, `../` означает переход на уровень выше

Comment: Зачем изгаляться и придумывать велосипед? Используйте PSR и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov композер находиться на уровень ниже и невозможно подключить автозагрузчик без указания пути на него.

Comment: @Станислав может стоит попробовать использовать функцию «chdir — Изменяет текущий каталог PHP на указанный» ?

Answer (score 2):

Вы вполне можете посмотеть как это сделано в laravel, насколько помню там используется:

`require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';`

[PSR](https://klisl.com/composer_autoload.html) - очень хорошая рекомендация! `autoload.php` генерирует composer, можете почитать об этом, в интернете очень много информации об этом, можете почитать, если Вам это интересно. [dirname](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.dirname) - возвращает полный путь к файлу или папке, которую указали в качестве параметра. `__DIR__` - [магическая константа](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.magic.php), которая хранит полный путь к директории, откуда её вызвали (утрированно очень описал).